# How to mock window object that contains third party object

Tags: angularjs, aws-appstream

I am using appstream embedded JavaScript file in my controller and getting appstream object from $window. But while mocking $window i don't have object for appstream bceause it is thirdparty content when iframe loaded.How can i write unit tests ?

In my controller i am accessing appstream object

```
var appstreamEmbed;
var _appStream = $window.AppStream;
```

Comment: You can just assign the AppStream object to $window object before calling your controller so that when controller is called AppStream object will be available the way it is required .

Comment: I have tried to assign appstream object in before each.

var window ={};
window.AppStream ={name : 'appstream'}
but window.appstream is undefined

Comment: You are creating the new object, so it will not work. You should assign it directly to $window object after you have injected in Unit test. Hope this helps.